# Is it okay to use the meta description as summary for a blog listing?

Tags: seo, technical-seo

I am wondering if using the meta description on the listing blog page (as summary next to the post title and the read more link) would have any kind of penalization as "duplicated content" or something like that. 
[image: Image for clarification]

**random blog design from internet*

Answer (score 1):

That should not be an issue for you, assuming the description/summary for each post is different.

In the image you posted they are all the same, which would be duplicative. But I assume that is just because it is Lorem Ipsum and not how it would be in production.

One purpose of meta description is to give users a quick summary of content to inform whether they should read more. So that is essentially a summary.

Answer (score 1):

It's ok! Actually, the meta description is not even a ranking factor since years. It can only give more attention to your page in SERPs, when it's shown, because it's not always displayed.

This little paragraph won't be considered as duplicated content. If it was larger and it was listed on a lot of pages again and again (categories, tags, archive by years, months, days, author, and so on), then I would say: yes.